# How can I summarize in MySQL a table to obtain a 3 month revenue average based on several columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, average, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I need some help. I trying to run a query in MySQL that would summarize a table that cotains revenue. The challenge I;m facing is that in the table we have information by month, by customer and region, and not all customers have a record of revenue each month, what I'm trying to accomplish is to summarize the table, by customer and region and obtain the average of the last 3 months of revenue recorded for each customer.

Sample table

[image: sample Table]

Expected Result

[image: Result]

how can this be accomplish?

Comment: Rafa, welcome to Stack Overflow. Try formatting your post using the guidelines from [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

One option uses window functions, available in MySQL 8.0:

```
select customer_name, region, avg(revenue) avg_revenue_last_3_months
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by customer_name, region order by month desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn <= 3
group by customer_name, region
```